# SQL Server 2008 R2 cluster, "available storage" shows "offline"

Tags: sql-server, cluster, failovercluster

I've installed a SQL Server 2008 R2 cluster and I found the resource group "available storage" shows "offline" status. What does it mean? It seems I can't take it online. I tried to use the `cluster resource` command and it shows that there seems no resource in this group. Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any disk in the same cluster group as your SQL Server? If not, that's your problem. You can only put databases on drives that will be guaranteed to be on the same node as your server. Also, the disk needs to be a cluster dependency for the SQL service, from what I can remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Available storage, if you have available storage in your cluster storage group part and dont use this any service/application/group you can see online, offline mean you dont have any available storage for your use.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say here -- can you clarify your answer?

Comment: That's doesn't seem to be exactly right about storage availability... I have an SQL cluster on W2008R2 and "Available Storage" group is online although.
While on another W2008R2 cluster the "Available Storage" group is offline after restart.

Running: cluster group "available storage" /online - brought it online.